# Using await in synchrounous function

Tags: azure, async-await, synchronous

I am using PdfMake library, and posting the pdf as stream in azure blob,

```
   pdfMake.createPdf(fullContentForPDF).getBuffer(function (result) {

          const stream = getStream(result)

          const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)

          const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName)

          try {

            await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream, uploadOptions.bufferSize, 

              uploadOptions.maxBuffers,

               { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'application/pdf' } }

            )

            const url= blockBlobClient.url

          } catch (err) {

            context.res = {

              status: 400,

              body: `error occured and it is:  ${err}`

            }

          }

        })
```

I need to use await keyword in synchronous function, because, I need to wait for the file to be posted to azure blob and get the uri of the blob, so, I definetly has to use the await keyword.

I have tried using self executable function, but I am not getting `const url= blockBlobClient.url` value.

Question: 
How would I get the `const url= blockBlobClient.url` using await in synchrounous function?

Answer (score 0):

the await keyword must be used with an asynchronus function, and the function you are using await on must return a promise. example.

```
async function waitForCall() {
  await makeCall();
  console.log("finished")
}

function makeCall(){

 return fetch(....)
}
```